# How to pass in data from Node JS Express with Ember-Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, ember.js

I'm working on an Ember website with a Node JS Express API.  I'm using ember-ajax to connect to the API.

EDIT:

Ember version is 1.13

Ember Data : 1.13.15

The problem is Ember does the AJAX call as if it was directed towards localhost:4200 (Ember) when it should be sent towards localhost:9029 (Express).  Of course, this throws a 404.

How do I make it so it sends the request to the API instead of itself?  I've tried --pxy after ember s but that does not work.  It seems like it's ignoring the files I created.  I'm very new to Ember.

app/services/ajax.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AjaxService from 'ember-ajax/services/ajax';

export default AjaxService.extend({
  namespace: '/api',
  host: 'http://localhost:9029',
  trustedHosts: [
    'http://localhost:9029',
  ]
});
```

app/routes/test.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AjaxService from 'ember-ajax/services/ajax';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    ajax: Ember.inject.service(),

    model() {
        return this.get('ajax').request('/gimmieDatDate', {method: 'POST'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you write out the full command you used to run the server? Something like

```
ember s --proxy http://localhost:9029
```

should work.

Comment: That is what I mentioned using.  I noticed that a large part of my difficulty might be unknowingly using Ember Data features though.  Though I don't know the process of getting data from AJAX to Ember.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the host in your (application) adapter.

```
// app/adapters/application.js
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  host: 'https://api.example.com'
});
```

Docs: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_host-customization